# Clear all Windows 11 notifications with a short-cut key

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to have a short-cut key to clear all Windows 11 notifications using Autohotkey v2. This question was asked before but the answer given was for Autohotkey V1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code(F11 to clear):

```
CreateClass("Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener", IUserNotificationListenerStatics := "{FF6123CF-4386-4AA3-B73D-B804E5B63B23}", UserNotificationListenerStatics)
DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(UserNotificationListenerStatics+0)+6*A_PtrSize), "ptr", UserNotificationListenerStatics, "ptr*", listener)    ; get_Current
DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(listener+0)+6*A_PtrSize), "ptr", listener, "int*", accessStatus)  ; RequestAccessAsync
WaitForAsync(accessStatus)
if (accessStatus != 1)  {

    msgbox AccessStatus Denied
    exitapp

}

F11::
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(listener+0)+10*A_PtrSize), "ptr", listener, "int", 1, "ptr*", UserNotificationReadOnlyList)   ; GetNotificationsAsync
    WaitForAsync(UserNotificationReadOnlyList)
    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(UserNotificationReadOnlyList+0)+7*A_PtrSize), "ptr", UserNotificationReadOnlyList, "int*", count) ; count
    loop % count    {

        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(UserNotificationReadOnlyList+0)+6*A_PtrSize), "ptr", UserNotificationReadOnlyList, "int", A_Index-1, "ptr*", UserNotification)    ; get_Item
        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(UserNotification+0)+8*A_PtrSize), "ptr", UserNotification, "uint*", id)   ; get_Id
        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(listener+0)+13*A_PtrSize), "ptr", listener, "uint", id)   ; RemoveNotification
        ObjRelease(UserNotification)

    }
    ObjRelease(UserNotificationReadOnlyList)
    DllCall("psapi.dll\EmptyWorkingSet", "ptr", -1)

return


CreateClass(string, interface, ByRef Class) {

    CreateHString(string, hString)
    VarSetCapacity(GUID, 16)
    DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", "wstr", interface, "ptr", &GUID)
    result := DllCall("Combase.dll\RoGetActivationFactory", "ptr", hString, "ptr", &GUID, "ptr*", Class, "uint")
    if (result != 0)    {

        if (result = 0x80004002)
            msgbox No such interface supported
        else if (result = 0x80040154)
            msgbox Class not registered
        else
            msgbox error: %result%
        ExitApp

    }

    DeleteHString(hString)

}

CreateHString(string, ByRef hString)    {

    DllCall("Combase.dll\WindowsCreateString", "wstr", string, "uint", StrLen(string), "ptr*", hString)

}

DeleteHString(hString)  {

    DllCall("Combase.dll\WindowsDeleteString", "ptr", hString)

}

WaitForAsync(ByRef Object)  {

    AsyncInfo := ComObjQuery(Object, IAsyncInfo := "{00000036-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
    loop    {

        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(AsyncInfo+0)+7*A_PtrSize), "ptr", AsyncInfo, "uint*", status) ; IAsyncInfo.Status
        if (status != 0)    {

            if (status != 1)    {

                DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(AsyncInfo+0)+8*A_PtrSize), "ptr", AsyncInfo, "uint*", ErrorCode)  ; IAsyncInfo.ErrorCode
                msgbox AsyncInfo status error: %ErrorCode%
                ExitApp

            }

            ObjRelease(AsyncInfo)
            break

        }

        sleep 10

    }

    DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(Object+0)+8*A_PtrSize), "ptr", Object, "ptr*", ObjectResult)  ; GetResults
    ObjRelease(Object)
    Object := ObjectResult

}
```

[Source](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=17&t=88306)

[For V2](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=122787&p=545466)

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this combination:

1. WinKey + A (to open Action Center)
2. Shift + Tab + Tab (to set focus on "clear all")
3. Space

From my reference, the keystrokes can be automated using NirCmd or AHK easily.

Thank you